# Query Node.js , Sequelize and Mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I need to query two tables in a Node.js project.
The project uses Sequelize and Mysql.

When a user registers a post in 'postagens table', he records the email.
When accessing the view, I need to consult the user's full name in 'users table' and load it into the view.

```
<td> {{fullname}} </td>
```

What change should I make in 'app.js'?

Very thanks!

//app.js

```
    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    Post.findAll({ raw: true, where: {
        companyid: '3',
        enviado: '0'
    } }).then(function (posts) {
        res.render('home', { posts: posts });
    });
});
```

//home.handlebars

```
    <div class="card">
    <div class = "card-body">
<h1>Lista de Posts</h1>
<form class="new-post" action="/cad" method="get">
  <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Nova Postagem!</button>
</form>
<table class="table" width= 100%>
  <thead>
    <td>id</td>
    <td>Título</td>
    <td>Conteúdo</td>
    <td>Fullname</td>
    <td>Ações</td>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {{#each posts}}
    <tr>
      <td>{{id}}</td>
      <td>{{titulo}}</td>
      <td>{{conteudo}}</td>
      <td>{{fullname}}</td>
      <td>

          <form class="form-action" action="/edit/{{id}}" method="get">
            <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">edit</button>
          </form>

      </td>
      <td>

          <form class="form-action" action="/deletar/{{id}}" method="get">
            <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">delete</button>
          </form>


      </td>
    </tr>

    {{/each}}
  </tbody>
</table>

</div>
</div>
```

//table postagens

```
CREATE TABLE `postagens` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `titulo` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_general_ci',
    `conteudo` TEXT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_general_ci',
    `companyid` TEXT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_general_ci',
    `enviado` TEXT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_general_ci',
    `email` TEXT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_general_ci',
    `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=51
;
```

//table users

```
   CREATE TABLE `users` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `email` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    `password` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    `fullname` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=4
;
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to call users.findOne or users.findByPk and you need to pass that the id field of the user you want to display in in the request... however as for the change to your app file, i'm not really sure i get what is going on there... you always have it calling one query.... if you had something like apollo graphql on your node server then you would just pass a query in... you need some way to show you want to call a diff sequelize query

Comment: Thank you for your help.
However, I still need some more information to resolve.

Comment: Well i think you need to do some work to your node server to be able to decipher between requests and then i could give you more detail... if you want to call the user query your server must be capable of deciphering what data you are looking for.. you have it hard coded